# How to display Local datetime in django template from UTC datetime stored in database?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates

I want to display date time in visitors local timezone in DJango templates from date time stored in UTC format in Database. for that i have made following changes in different files.

**settings.py**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

**page.html**

```
{% load tz %}
<div>
    {{ start_time | localtime }}
</div>

and

<div>
    {% localtime on %} 
        {{ start_time }}
    {% endlocaltime %}
</div>
```

As this `start_time` is stores only 'HH:MM' in string format. But i have also tried with the date time object. still it doesn't works for me.

and one more issue, when i use `datetime.utcnow()` and `datetime.now()`, both gives me 'UTC' date time in **views.py**.

or suggest me, if any other way to get the same?

So can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: try to change LANGUAGE_CODE  in settings.py to your local.

Answer (score 0):

You got to use django [timezone module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/):

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

Comment: it also gives me UTC time.when i print to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple methods, still I was not able to achieve this purely in django though it is simple to implement in js. So I have implement it using Django Custom tag .

custom_filters.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def localTime(time): 
    time = time.isoformat(" ",'seconds')
    return f"<span id='django-local-field'></span>\n<script>\nd = new Date(Date.parse('{time}'));document.getElementById('django-local-field').innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();document.getElementById('django-local-field').removeAttribute('id');</script>"
```

file.html ( my template file )

```
{% load custom_filters %}
.
.
<p class="daysBox">local time:  {{ sub.expiryDate|localTime|safe }}</p>
.
.
.
```

"sub.expiryDate" is the time variable. Also you could edit "d.toLocaleString();" to customize the format.
Incase if you want my dir structure:

```
project(BASE_DIR)
|-- app
    |--- __init__.py
    |--- models.py
    |--- etc..
    |--- templatetags
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- custom_filters.py
```

Also, don't forget to restart the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django's automatic timestamp 
such as `auto_now_add=True` or `auto_now=True` Django will automatically convert the timestamp to UTC time. Therefore, before converting the timestamp to local time, you need to first convert it to UTC time. You can use the `timezone.make_aware()` to convert the timestamp to UTC time

```
from django.utils import timezone

utc_time = timezone.make_aware(my_model.timestamp, timezone.utc)
local_time = timezone.localtime(utc_time)
```